# How to add fake blanks in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i've copied from an else author from here the following line:

```
forfiles /P "C:\SomePath" /S /M test.txt /C "cmd /c if @ftime LSS %new_time% del /F /Q @path"
```

I've edited it for my purpose as an e-amil info system:

```
forfiles /P "C:\screenshots" /S /M "2_screenshot.jpg" /C "cmd /c if @ftime LSS %new_time% bmail -s smtpserver -t me@mail.com -f screenshot@mail.com -a TV 2 got a problem"
```

So, and here is my problem. When I've send it like this I only get a mail with "TV" as subject. When I am going to include the mail text into "" it will stop there. When I am going to add the command from bmail till problem into () it won't work as well.

Is there any workaround possible or is it possible to add some fake blanks in the text? In html I know `%20` for this purpose.

Comment: don't have `bmail`, but `... -a "TV 2 got a problem""` should do.

Comment: that was the first thing I've tried. But then the command will end at the second word after the first " --->    ´TV 2´ and end

Comment: Strange. According to [documentation](http://retired.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm), it should work. I see no reason, why it should break after two words. You surrounded the whole command line with quotes? `cmd /c "if @ftime LSS %new_time% bmail -s smtpserver -t me@mail.com -f screenshot@mail.com -a "TV 2 got a problem""`

Comment: If I am going to add the " before the if it will break immediatelly. Well, I guess I simplicy just add underlines instead of blanks. that will work.

Comment: Hm - `forfiles` seems to have an own parser. Try `forfiles /P "C:\screenshots" /S /M "2_screenshot.jpg" /C "cmd /c echo """TV 2 got a problem""""` (yes, it looks ugly...)

Comment: wow, that worked. I tried with two already, but I didn't thought at three. Thanks a lot. Maybe you can add this as answer so I can mark this as solved and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forfiles seems to have an own parser, which makes it neccessary to escape the quotes. The standard way of escaping `^"` does not work, with `forfiles` we need to give it *three* quotes to remain a single one.

```
forfiles /P "C:\screenshots" /S /M "2_screenshot.jpg" /C "cmd /c echo """TV 2 got a problem""""
```

(yes, it looks ugly...)